# Generating Firebase Auth Anonymous User to represent a desktop installation?

Tags: firebase-authentication

In the software I'm writing, you login to your account for a piece of desktop software, and then many users use the software at a business location (It's not associated with a single user). To allow the desktop software to make requests that aren't directly associated with a single user account, I'm generating a new user behind the scenes for every desktop software link.

I create a user through the Admin SDK that just has a user id (no name, or email, or phone number etc), and give it a custom claim that allows me to differentiate it from the rest of the real user accounts. If the install is unlinked, I delete the user from Firebase.

Is this an acceptable way of using Firebase Auth users? **The main thing I'm concerned about is the refresh token expiring** or something like that.

Comment: How do you intend to create the user?

Comment: Using the Java Admin SDK. FirebaseAuth.createUser, where I supply a user id, and then FirebaseAuth.createCustomToken

Comment: Thanks for clarifying  --- I don't really see any issue with that, so I recommend trying it and reporting back if you (unexpectedly) run into problems.